# Sencha Touch : [WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`some_id`) which has already been used

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch-2

I have a navigation view. On click of a button, I am trying to push another view into this navigation view by calling the below function:

```
showNewView: function () {
    Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().push({
        title: 'New View',
        xtype: 'newview'
    });
```

This **newview** has an id **some_id**.

Now when I call this function more than once, I get the below warning:

```
[WARN][Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id (`some_id`)
which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been 
destroyed (`Ext.Component#destroy()`.
```

- I understand that this warning shows up because during the second
  time thie function is called, a **newview** is being created with
  same **id**. And **id** needs to be unique. Hence the warning.
- Also, I know that instead of **id**, i can use **itemId** which will 
  serve the purpose of referencing that particular component.

What I want to know is, if I continue using **id**, how do I destroy the existing component as explained in warning??

Is there something wrong the way I am creating it in the first place?  `Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem().push({ title: 'New View', xtype: 'newview' });`

Or is the above fine and do I need to destroy the component at some point? Maybe during the pop event? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

When you call it more than once, you are basically creating 2 views which have same id's.

Solutions:

```
if(!Ext.getCmp('newview')){

Ext.create('Org_name.Basic_name.view.newview');

}

Ext.getCmp('newview').show();
```

1. Check if id exists and then create the view, after that show it
2. remove the id attribute